# ASP.NET MVC when remove shopping cart from database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crud, shopping-cart

I made a shopping cart through this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8).

The question is, when the user adds the products to the cart and stores it in the database, but does not log in or register and leave the site, then when should the cart items be deleted from the database and how?

Comment: That is a business rule, get (make up) a requirement. Marketing might say 'never' because they want to analyze those baskets.

Answer (score 2):

you can do following things

1) if user is unauthorized and adds item then you can assign it an unique id

---

2) you can create cookie to store that id at client side

---

3) store items in database using that id

---

4) in case session gets timed out you can read that cookie and retrieve  id

---

5) you can fix a time duration(example : 1 week) for that items if user takes no action on them you can clean it up.

Comment: Thanks, Please explain more about steps 4 and 5

Comment: in step 4 you will have cookie at client side(on users machine) containing that unique id. you can check for that cookie if it contains unique id so you can retrieve records of that user using that unique id.

Comment: step 5 in case user have added some items and that items got stored in database using that unique id and that user never performs any action or never came back then you need to database clean up right ? in that case you can make scheduler that clean up those entries if those entries are untouched for 1 week (lets assume you have defined 1 week).